# Pass function arguments into Julia non-interactively

Tags: julia

I have a Julia function in a file. Let's say it is the below. Now I want to pass arguments into this function. I tried doing

```
julia filename.jl randmatstat(5)
```

but this gives an error that '(' token is unexpected. Not sure what the solution would be. I am also a little torn on if there is a main function / how to write a full solution using Julia. For example what is the starting / entry point of a Julia Program?

```
function randmatstat(t)
    n = 5
    v = zeros(t)
    w = zeros(t)
    for i = 1:t
        a = randn(n,n)
        b = randn(n,n)
        c = randn(n,n)
        d = randn(n,n)
        P = [a b c d]
        Q = [a b; c d]
        v[i] = trace((P.'*P)^4)
        w[i] = trace((Q.'*Q)^4)
    end
    std(v)/mean(v), std(w)/mean(w)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia doesn't have an "entry point" as such.
When you call `julia myscript.jl` from the terminal, you're essentially asking julia to execute the script and exit. As such, it needs to be a script. If all you have in your script is a function definition, then it won't do much unless you later call that function from your script.

As for arguments, if you call `julia myscript.jl 1 2 3 4`, all the remaining arguments (i.e. in this case, 1, 2, 3 and 4) become an array of strings with the special name `ARGS`. You can use this special variable to access the input arguments.

e.g. if you have a julia script which simply says:

```
# in julia mytest.jl
show(ARGS)
```

Then calling this from the linux terminal will give this result:

```
<bashprompt> $ julia mytest.jl 1 two "three and four"
UTF8String["1","two","three and four"]
```

**EDIT:** So, from what I understand from your program, you probably want to do something like this (note: in julia, the function needs to be defined before it's called).

```
# in file myscript.jl
function randmatstat(t)
    n = 5
    v = zeros(t)
    w = zeros(t)
    for i = 1:t
        a = randn(n,n)
        b = randn(n,n)
        c = randn(n,n)
        d = randn(n,n)
        P = [a b c d]
        Q = [a b; c d]
        v[i] = trace((P.'*P)^4)
        w[i] = trace((Q.'*Q)^4)
    end
    std(v)/mean(v), std(w)/mean(w)
end

t = parse(Int64, ARGS[1])
(a,b) = randmatstat(t)
print("a is $a, and b is $b\n")
```

And then call this from your linux terminal like so:

```
julia myscript.jl 5
```

Comment: Note: If you want output to the linux terminal from your script, you need to ask for it explicitly with the print command (or something equivalent). Also, this is just a demo, in a proper program you should be testing if the user gave the right number of arguments etc to prevent user error.

Comment: Also, in case what you were after wasn't specifically running from the linux terminal, but just getting your result, and you're happy doing it in the interactive julia prompt, and you just want to know how to run a script, then all you need to do is `include("myscript.jl")` at the julia prompt

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to pass the argument to the script and not care about writing it internally as a function... the reason is that with the a functions, there are some difficulties about top scope and loading packages, especially if you want to use a parpool (for example when calling myscript from a PBS-script)

Answer (score 5):

You can try running like so:

`julia -L filename.jl -E 'randmatstat(5)'`

Comment: This will "work" but strictly speaking it is not the answer to OP's problem, as it bypasses the issue of "what's the entry point of a julia program". This simply ensures the function defined in the filename is loaded first, and then executes an arbitrary statement. It is worth clearing the misunderstanding that a function defined in a file can be called directly, as this likely stems from people coming from the matlab world.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your Julia file:

```
### original file
function randmatstat...
...
end

### new stuff
if length(ARGS)>0
    ret = eval(parse(join(ARGS," ")))
end
println(ret)
```

Now, you can run:

```
julia filename.jl "randmatstat(5)"
```

As attempted originally. Note the additional quotes added to make sure the parenthesis don't mess up the command.

Explanation: The `ARGS` variable is defined by Julia to hold the parameters to the command running the file. Since Julia is an interpreter, we can `join` these parameters to a string, parse it as Julia code, run it and print the result (the code corresponds to this description).

Comment: is there a way to capture the options used when starting julia? or those can only be retrieved via other constants? like `julia -p 2` can be obtained with `nprocs()`

Comment: `opts = Base.JLOptions()` gives all the "raw" options used by Julia. The structure has several fields which need to be interpreted. Look at `base/options.jl` for details. Perhaps some OS specific way to get the command-line from the PID might also be an option ;)