# Cannot run julia file - syntax error close to the unexpected token

Tags: linux, julia

Well, i wrote a simple "hello world" in julia, but i cannot figure out on how to run the code. I've tried to run by `./nameOfMyFile.jl` and the terminal returned to me that I have syntax errors.

My code is just:

```
println("hello world")
```

Wich works perfectly if i run `julia` on the terminal and write the code after that...

The error is something like( **I am translating it from portuguese**):

```
./hello_world.jl: line 1:syntax error close to the unexpected token `"hello world"

./hello_world.jl: line 1: `println("hello world")'
```

I'm using vim, debian 8 and julia 0.3.2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Rather than changing the title of a question to use "solved" you can just click the green check box next to the answer that solved the question for you.  That will let future people know that the question has been solved.  And, once you get 15 rep points, you can also upvote any answers that were helpful to you by clicking on the arrows by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of to achieve what you want

Open a terminal and do either one of the following

Inside the julia relp, that is, if you run julia in the terminal by running

```
julia
```

and when you're in, do

```
include("nameoffile.jl")
```

if you simple want to run the file, in the terminal do

```
julia nameoffile.jl
```

Comment: @RenatoFerreira also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533981/pass-function-arguments-into-julia-non-interactively/38461729#38461729

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute it directly from the terminal you can add a shebang to the beggining of your script i.e.

`#!/usr/bin/env julia
println("hello world")`

and then make it executable using chmod

`[user@computer]$ chmod +x hello`

then it should run as expected :)

`./hello`

will print "hello world" to your terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussions on GitHub like [this one](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10110) it sounds like this issue is more due to the shell than to Julia.  Nevertheless, I would strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Julia, 0.4.6.  The version that you are using is quite old and lacks a lot of improvements, including ones addressing issues at least similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thaks by the advice, i will certainly upgrade my julia version, altough the answer of isebarn has solved my trouble.