# How to make Julia file execute like a sh file?

Tags: linux, julia

I have a julia script hello.jl with following content:

```
print("Hello world")
```

How to make it execute like a .sh file i.e. on double click on it?
I am using Linux Mint 21, and have julia installed the bash environment.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745787

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run julia file - syntax error close to the unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724210/cannot-run-julia-file-syntax-error-close-to-the-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Alexander Morley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5472203/alexander-morley) said (via [@August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498956/august)) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745787/):

> If you want to execute it directly from the terminal you can add a
> shebang to the beginning of your script e.g. [create a file called "hello" with the following as it's contents:
>
> #!/usr/bin/env julia
>
> println("hello world")
>
> [then make it executable by running the following in the folder it is within]
>
> [user@computer]$ chmod +x hello
>
> then it should run as expected :)
>
> ./hello